# Excel: display a text when the count of list is less than two

Tags: excel, vba

I need to display the word "other" when the count of a list is less than two.

For example,
I have a column with gender and another with nationality.

When the count of nationality is less than two I need to display the word "other".

Is there a way to do this in Excel without writing VBA?

Comment: Hey there; have you tried Googling this yet or posting an example of the sorts of formulae you have tried?

Comment: Also a minimum worked example of your problem (ie. an example input with desired output) helps.

Comment: what do you mean by "display" . do you mean a popup dialog box?

Comment: what does "count of nationality" mean?  ...your request is very unclear .... did you translate the question from another language?

Comment: sorry I will try to explain it... i have a column with values (USA, JAPAN, India, Jordan) i need to count the number of occurrences then display the word "other" if the count is less than two

Answer (score 1):

Mike, If the cell that you need to display this in is one other than where the value is kept, then you would use the formula,

`=IF(A1<2,"Other",A1)`

If, on the other hand, you need to display 'Other' in the same cell as where the value is kept, then you would change the number format of those cells to the custom format:

`[<2]"Other";#`

To do this, select the cell, or cells, right-click > Format Cells > Custom.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like that display formatting option concept.  I would hate you for doing it in one of my spreadsheets, but I love the concept!

Answer (score 0):

[image: POC]

Assuming your list of countries is listed in D19:D30 with D19 being a header.

You can use the following formula to generate a list of unique country names.  place the formula in F20 and copy down as required.

```
=INDEX($D$20:$D$30, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($F$19:F19, $D$20:$D$30), 0))
```

The above formula is a CSE or <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> formula.  Use that keyboard combination when entering the formula instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  When done right it will surround your formula with {}.  Note you cannot add {} manually around the formula.

In cell G20, place the following formula and copy it down as far as your unique country list extends.  It will place the country count or display other when the country count occurrence is less than 2.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($D$20:$D$30,F20)<2,"Other",COUNTIF($D$20:$D$30,F20))
```